# WAAD Logout redirecting to office 365 login page

Tags: authentication, wif, logout, ws-federation

Facing an issue with logout from my application using  WSfederationAuthentication. On logout I execute the following code :

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            if (FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule != null)
            {
                FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
                FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
            }

            if (FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule != null)
            {
                WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule =
                    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
                authModule.SignOut(true);

                String signoutURL = WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(
                    authModule.Issuer,
                    authModule.Realm",
                    null);

                WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(
                    new Uri(signoutURL),
                    new Uri(authModule.Realm));                    
            }
```

The cookies are cleared etc, but the page is redirected to office365 login page instead of my applications proper login page.

The Issuer and Realm are correct 
    Issuer : https://login.windows.net/EndpointID/wsfed
    Realm : https//:localhost:444 (base address of my application, localhost)

Following is the fiddler log after I click logout :

```
http://login.windows.net:443
https://login.windows.net/EndpointID/wsfed?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https%3a%2f%2f127.0.0.1%3a444%2f
https://localhost:444/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0
http://login.microsoftonline.com:443
https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignout1.0
https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf?wa=wsignout1.0&lc=1033
https://login.windows.net/common/wsfed?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0  **<<<<------ Why ?**
http://login.microsoftonline-p.com:443 
https://login.microsoftonline-p.com/ThirdPartyCookieCheck.srf?ct=9348739876
https://login.microsoftonline-p.com/ThirdPartyCookieCheck.srf?tpc=394875457987&lc=1033
https://login.microsoftonline.com/?lc=1033
```

These guys are facing similar issue,  no resolution : 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac41c0c5-83ef-4394-9111-fa6d07215f5d/adfs-20-does-not-redirect-back-to-reply-url-on-signout?forum=Geneva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no replies here I can assume that no one else has ever got this issue :D.

I found a solution for those who land here searching for the same.

So according to 'WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut' documentation on MSDN :

> Call this method to send a WS-Federation sign-out request message tothe specified STS. You can optionally supply a value for the wreply parameter in the sign-out request. The method does the following:
>
> 1. Creates a WS-Federation sign-out request message by using the specified parameters.
> 2. Calls the SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie method on the SAM to delete the session cookie.
> 3. Redirects to the STS using the sign-out request message from the first step.

For some reason for me this was not working as advertised :( . So I decided to these 3 things manually which worked flawlessly. Problem solved for now but still wondering why is the provided wrapper not working.

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();

WSFederationAuthenticationModule wsfederationAuthenticationModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
wsfederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut(true);
signOutRequestMessageuestMessage signOutRequestMessage = new signOutRequestMessageuestMessage(new Uri(wsfederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer));
signOutRequestMessage.Parameters.Add("wreply", wsfederationAuthenticationModule.Realm);
signOutRequestMessage.Parameters.Add("wtrealm", wsfederationAuthenticationModule.Realm);
signOutURI = signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString();
Redirect(signOutURI)
```

Hope this helps.

Gaurav